# Unix: unique based on first 24 bytes of IP

Tags: unix, uniq

I have a file that has the following IP's:

```
64.5.12.3
64.5.12.8
122.4.5.1
122.4.5.6
```

How to unique based on only the first 24 bytes such that, the output is:

```
64.5.12
122.4.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cut` and `sort`:

```
cut -c-7 inputfile | sort -u
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
122.4.5
64.5.12
```

---

If I understand it correct, you might want to use the following:

```
cut -d. -f-3 inputfile | sort -u
```

Comment: I think the second case is far more likely than the first one - it's more to do with splitting by subnet rather than by character

Comment: @Petesh Indeed, that was the precise reason behind mentioning it.